# Selenium tests failed because Chrome failed to start in non-headless mode

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, selenium-chromedriver

**Environment**

- Azure ADO classic pipeline
- Microsoft-hosted agents Build info:version: '4.14.1', revision: '03f8ede370'
- System info: os.name:'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2.0-1018-azure'

**Problem**
When the test started, we got these exceptions:

```
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
 
(session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
```

**Classic pipeline as yaml**

```yaml
# Variable 'baseURL' was defined in the Variables tab
# Variable 'browser' was defined in the Variables tab
variables:
- name: BuildParameters.mavenPOMFile
  value: pom.xml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - refs/heads/main
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r)
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: self
    type: git
    ref: main
jobs:
- job: Job_1
  displayName: Agent job 1
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    clean: true
    fetchTags: false
  - task: JavaToolInstaller@0
    displayName: Use Java 17
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 17
      jdkArchitectureOption: x64
      jdkSourceOption: PreInstalled
  - task: MavenAuthenticate@0
    displayName: Authenticate for Azure Artifacts
    inputs:
      artifactsFeeds: azure-artifacts
  - task: Maven@4
    displayName: Build bdd-test
    inputs:
      mavenPOMFile: $(BuildParameters.mavenPOMFile)
      goals: verify
      options: --no-transfer-progress -DskipITs=false -DbaseURL=$(baseURL) -Dbrowser=$(browser)
  - task: NodeTool@0
    displayName: Install Node for Cucumber
    inputs:
      versionSpec: 12.x
  - task: MaciejMaciejewski.azure-pipelines-cucumber.PublishCucumberReport.PublishCucumberReport@1
    displayName: Publish Cucumber Report
    inputs:
      jsonDir: bdd-test/target/cucumber
      outputPath: bdd-test/target/cucumber
      metadata: >-
        {
          "Base URL": "$(baseURL)",
          "Browser": "$(browser)"
        }
      name: BDD
      title: Test
...
```

Added chrome driver log
**ChromeDriver log**

```
[1703011948.085][INFO]: Use the --remote-debugging-pipe Chrome switch instead of the default --remote-debugging-port to enable this communication mode.
[1703011948.085][INFO]: Launching chrome: /opt/google/chrome/chrome --allow-pre-commit-input --disable-background-networking --disable-client-side-phishing-detection --disable-default-apps --disable-dev-shm-usage --disable-hang-monitor --disable-popup-blocking --disable-prompt-on-repost --disable-sync --enable-automation --enable-logging --ignore-certificate-errors --log-level=0 --no-first-run --no-sandbox --no-service-autorun --password-store=basic --remote-debugging-port=0 --test-type=webdriver --use-mock-keychain --user-data-dir=/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.A6NuzC data:,
[1929:1929:1219/185228.380273:ERROR:ozone_platform_x11.cc(239)] Missing X server or $DISPLAY
[1929:1929:1219/185228.380300:ERROR:env.cc(257)] The platform failed to initialize.  Exiting.
[1219/185228.408089:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(354)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly
[1703011948.448][INFO]: [30db2e7b6389e60968ecef7e960cfdf9] RESPONSE InitSession ERROR session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
[1703011948.448][DEBUG]: Log type 'driver' lost 0 entries on destruction
[1703011948.448][DEBUG]: Log type 'browser' lost 0 entries on destruction
```

Comment: Hi, where do you get the _Microsoft-hosted agents Build info_ and _System info_? I can't find a 
[Microsoft-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#software)  with the information you shared. Please share more details of the issue, such as pipeline definition , debug logs or sample code to reproduce the issue. You can [export your Classic pipeline to a YAML file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/migrate/from-classic-pipelines?view=azure-devops#export-your-classic-pipeline) and share it.

Comment: The Build info and System info was reported by Maven

I try the ubuntu-latest, ubuntu-22.04 and ubuntu-20.04 all failed. However, windows-latest was OK. Also, when the test run in headless mode it worked fine as well.

Comment: Hi, can you refer [this ticket solution](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Custom-Linux-hosted-build-agent-version-/10189806#T-N10190994) to collect the chromedriver log and check the  source of the Chrome crash? It will help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: chromedriver.log added

Answer (score 0):

According to [Headless mode or visible UI mode?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#headless-mode-or-visible-ui-mode) and [Decide how you will deploy and test your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/continuous-test-selenium?view=azure-devops#decide-how-you-will-deploy-and-test-your-app),

> Visible UI mode (non-headless mode). In this mode, the browser runs normally and the UI components are visible. When running tests in this mode on Windows, [special configuration of the agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-mode) is required.

> When using the Microsoft-hosted agent, you should use the Selenium web drivers that are pre-installed on the **Windows agents** because they are compatible with the browser versions installed on the Microsoft-hosted agent images.  The drivers are **not pre-installed** on other agents such as **Linux, Ubuntu, and macOS agents**.

It explains that why it works when you choose the windows-latest agent. So, it is suggested to use the Microsoft-hosted windows agent instead of the Microsoft-hosted Ubuntu agent.

Comment: I used WebDriver Manager (https://bonigarcia.dev/webdrivermanager/), and it would install any missing WebDriver automatically; from the log it did. Even in headless mode, WebDriver was required (and I had no problem running in headless mode). I think the problem is that the Ubuntu environment was not ready to run XServer, so Chromium could not start.

Comment: oh, thanks for your explanation. I am not sure if you can configure XServer on Ubuntu. Maybe you can try to use self-hosted agent. This would give you more control over the environment and installed software.